# How to disable certain option in the exporting option of Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and I add the following sript for export option and I would like to disbles the `View in full screen`, `View data table` and  `Open in Highcharts Cloud` option.

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

[image: Exporting option]

Comment: did you search the docs about this ? there has to be an option where you can specify which items you want to have in the exporting options

Comment: I searched but I just found an option who disable all exporting option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `"viewFullscreen"` item from `menuItems` array:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: [
                'printChart',
                'separator',
                'downloadPNG',
                'downloadJPEG',
                'downloadPDF',
                'downloadSVG'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6985zcwa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems